# Define monitor for PyQt6 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm wondering how to explicitly define the monitor for the application to start on.
The application yields:

```
qt.qpa.window: Window position QRect(468,-22 504x896)
outside any known screen, using primary screen
```

Upon execution.
The `MainWindow` object is loosely defined as below:

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def center(self):
        """
        Center window in middle of screen 2
        """

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = self.screen().availableGeometry().center()

        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.center()
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Init window
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

I'm on a Mac laptop where i have multiple virtual desktops, which are assumed by `PyQt6` to be physical monitors.

How do I explicitly set the application to open on the primary / 1st monitor?

Comment: what is the output of `print(self.screen().availableGeometry())`

Comment: @eyllanesc `PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(0, 25, 1440, 804)`

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Is the initial calculation of the position wrong, or is `move()` not working as expected? What are the actual values at each stage of the calculation of the required position?

Comment: @ekhumoro It returns `PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(0, 25, 1440, 801)` right before i define the `Qwindow` object and set the primary screen. Which is in fact different from the original comment. How do i check / fix `move()`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan What are the values of  `cp` and `qr` (both before and after calling `moveCenter()`)? Also, what is the actual position of the window after it's shown on screen? You haven't actually said whether it ends up in the expected position or not. Is the "problem" simply that Qt prints that message - or what exactly?

Comment: @ekhumoro Before:`qr` = `PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 503, 895)`. `cp` = `PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(719, 425)`. After `qr` = `PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(468, -22, 503, 895)`. `cp` = `PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(719, 425)`. The window goes to the primary screen, and is located in the center. The problem is that the messages appear. I would like to define the monitor instead of letting pyqt assume what monitor to use. In the future I will define a specific monitor for the program to open on.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan So the default height for the window (`895`) is greater than the available screen height (`801`). Given that, the warning message seems reasonable and correct. Presumably, if you resize the window to a sane height (i.e. <= `801`) before making the calculation, the message will go away. Your other points about monitors do not make sense, since your laptop only has one. Multiple desktops aren't equivalent to multiple monitors. Desktops are the province of the window-manager, which Qt has no control over.

Comment: self.move(QApplication.screens()[monitor].availableGeometry().center())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like below. (I don't have environment. I did not try.). Let me know if this is not working. I will remove this post.

```
#MAINWINDOW OBJECT
window = MainWindow()

#GET QWINDOW OBJECT
win = window.windowHandle()

#SET PRIMARY SCREEN
win.setScreen(app.primaryScreen()) #app is your application object.
```

Also there is a note in the documentation

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QWindow.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QWindow.setScreen

> Note: If the screen is part of a virtual desktop of multiple screens,
> the window will not move automatically to newScreen. To place the
> window relative to the screen, use the screen's topLeft() position.

You can also try by getting all the available screens

```
screens = app.screens()
```

May be you can iterate them and set the screen you want to.

```
win.setScreen(screens[0]) #example
```

Comment: change `win = QWindow(window.windowHandle())` to `win = window.windowHandle()`. With your code you are creating a new QWindow that has "window.windowHandle()" as parent

Comment: `win.setScreen(app.primaryScreen())` yields `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setScreen'`, when using `win = window.windowHandle()`. However, `QWindow(window.windowHandle())` doesn't throw an error, but warns of original problem of `qt.qpa.window: Window position QRect(468,-21 504x896) outside any known screen, using primary screen`